# inertia + vue, send props to sub components?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have two components :

- Page.vue

  - Component.vue

In my Laravel route I do

```
return inertia('Page', [ 'foo' => Model::all()->map(...) ]);
```

In Page I do:

```
<template> 
  <Component/>
</template>
<script setup>
    defineProps({ foo: Array });
</script>
```

Would it be possible to access `foo`, without transiting by `Page`? When using nested components. It looks cumbersome to always forward props like `<Component :foo='foo'>`.

In this case, only `Component` use `foo` which is not directly used in `Page`.

Comment: If I understand what you need, I think you can use inertia share (https://inertiajs.com/shared-data#accessing-shared-data) In that way you can access shared data from component directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share a prop data to a subcomponent this way:

Route:

```php
Route::get('/example', function () {
    return inertia('Page', [
        'someData' => 'foo'
    ]);
});
```

1st component (`Page.vue`) - Here you pass in the data to the subcomponent:

```html
<template>
  <Component :someData="$page.props.someData" />
</template>

<script setup>
  import Component from '../Pages/Component.vue'
</script>
```

2nd component (`Component.vue`) - And here you retrieve it:

```html
<template>
  {{ someData }}
</template>

<script setup>
  const props = defineProps({
    someData: String,
  })

  const someData = props.someData
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, but in this case it is boilerplate. The data of Component have to flow by Page. This is what I would like to avoid.